# Why does my element overlap another element?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website and I have a problem with the CSS parts. I have a two element with a padding for the child inside the element but i want to get the child inisde the element solid

Image example:
[image]

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 438px;
  height: 290px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.child {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 186px auto 0px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 327px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <h5>Hotel Mediterranean</h5>
    <p>Work with Garden is a great honorable sessions because we love it and what we’re doing so we w’ll work with Garden for ever !</p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- The other element -->
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <h5>Hotel Mediterranean</h5>
    <p>Work with Garden is a great honorable sessions because we love it and what we’re doing so we w’ll work with Garden for ever !</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `z-index` issue?

Comment: Not tech help but it's spelt 'Mediterranean'

Comment: I changed the "Mediterraneen" to "Mediterranean", thank you @d219

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code, run the code snippet and check it out I hope it meets your expectation.

```css
.main-div{
height:auto;
width:438px;
margin:8px;
text-align:center;
}
.parent {
position: relative;
border-radius:10px;
width: 438px;
height: 290px;
background-image: url("https://png.pngtree.com/thumb_back/fw800/back_pic/03/97/34/1457f06a227e6ce.jpg");
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;


box-sizing: border-box;
}
.child {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
background-color:#ebebeb;
border-radius:8px;
margin-top:-60px;
width: 300px;
height: auto;
}
h3{
line-height:30px;
border-radius:8px;
margin:0px;
background-color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="main-div">
<div class="parent"></div>
<div class="child">
<h3>Hotel Mediterraneen</h3>
<p>Work with Garden is a great honorable sessions because we love it and what we’re doing so we w’ll work with Garden for ever !</p>
</div>
</div>  

<!-- The other element -->

<div class="main-div">
<div class="parent"></div>
<div class="child">
<h3>Hotel Mediterraneen</h3>
<p>Work with Garden is a great honorable sessions because we love it and what we’re doing so we w’ll work with Garden for ever !</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ^^:
And thanks for remaking the page it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

you have set fixed height value for parent and child, the sum of the margin and the height of the child is bigger then the parent height, try to set min-height on parent and not height:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 438px;
  min-height: 290px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Be careful with hardcoding a width using px. It's better to use percentage. For example: width: 40% instead of width: 438px. Take into consideration multiple viewports.